# Get salesforce dependent picklist using php

Tags: php, salesforce

I use PHP code for get the picklist and their dependent list using describe "Task". It returns the all dependent values but i am unable to get set the parent and child values from the reponse. Validfor option is empty for some fields. Anyone please help me to show all dependent fields in my page.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Excuse me, E. Parker answer should be marked as **correct** if it fits correct for you.

Answer (score 2):

After researching and struggling with the same issue for some time, I came across the following website that contained a solution along with a good explanation of how they achieved it:

http://jaswinderjohal.com/salesforce-dependent-list-php/

The solution uses the `describeSObject` method provided in the Salesforce PHP Metadata API. I developed the complete script (shown below) by slightly modifying the code given at the provided link.

The script returns a JSON encoded array of arrays, where each sub array contains just two items; the first item is the name of the parent category picklist value, and the second item is an array containing the names of the children picklist values that apply to that parent value. Of course the JSON encoding is optional, just remove the `echo json_encode($finalApplicableOptions);` line (this was done only to demonstrate what the output looks like).

Example script output:

```
[["Category 1",["Cat1 Child1", "Cat1 Child2", ... ]],["Category 2",["Cat2 Child1", "Cat2 Child2", ... ]], ...]
```

It seems as though you need to describe the "Task" object, so just use `$mySforceConnection->describeSObject('Task')` as shown in the script below.
Then, be sure to change the `"Parent_Category_Name_Goes_Here"` placeholder string to match the "name" property of the parent field, and change the `"Child_Category_Name_Goes_Here"` placeholder string to match the "name" property of the child field, in order to specify which fields you wish to get the dependent picklist values for.

```
<?php

// ** Create $mySforceConnection here as normal **

$result = $mySforceConnection->describeSObject('Task');

$finalApplicableOptions = array(array());

for($i=0; $i < count($result->fields); $i++){
    if($result->fields[$i]->name == "Parent_Category_Name_Goes_Here"){
        $sub = count($result->fields[$i]->picklistValues);
        for($j=0;$j < $sub; $j++){
            $finalApplicableOptions[$j][0] = $result->fields[$i]->picklistValues[$j]->label;
            $finalApplicableOptions[$j][1] = array();
        }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i < count($result->fields); $i++){
    if($result->fields[$i]->name == "Child_Category_Name_Goes_Here"){
        for($j=0;$j < count($result->fields[$i]->picklistValues); $j++){
            $byteArr = $result->fields[$i]->picklistValues[$j]->validFor;
            $maparray = array();
            $map = "";
            foreach(str_split(base64_decode($byteArr)) as $c)
                $maparray [] = sprintf("%08b", ord($c));
            $map = implode("", $maparray);
            for ($k = 0; $k < strlen($map); $k++){
                if($map{$k} == "1")
                    $finalApplicableOptions[$k][1][] =
                        $result->fields[$i]->picklistValues[$j]->label;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($finalApplicableOptions);

?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer congrats.

Comment: I tried implementing your script but the values are mismatching.

Comment: The code above has one small mistake. `foreach(str_split($byteArr) as $c)` needs to be `foreach(str_split(base64_decode($byteArr)) as $c)`. Wrap `$byteArr` in the `base64_decode()` function and it should work.